# How to get the test steps counts of a Test set in Test lab?

Tags: hp-alm-12.20

I have to get the test steps count of all the test cases separately from the test lab. Since test cases pulled in this test set is from different folders of test plan so I need some query which can give me result in based on Test set in test lab.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to extract all the test cases from HP ALM with test steps in an excel and then use formula to count the steps for each test case. This will be lot quicker and save loads of manual efforts

Answer (score 0):

1. Create folder structure in Test Lab (most of the time same as in
   Test Plan but not necessary)
2. Now Pull the corresponding test cases from Test Plan to Test Lab
   [image]

   In this article you are going to learn how to create folder structure in Test lab and Mapping or pulling test cases from Test Plan to Test Lab.